# Android Date Picker - Actual Date minus X number of days

Tags: android, android-calendar

I can get the current date with the following code to show in DatePicker dialog for example.

```
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

How can I show the actual date minus 18years (more or less 6570days)?

From my "research" I need to use `DAY_OF_YEAR`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
    c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18);
```

You shouldn't have to worry about the "more or less" of 6570 days since a Calendar object handles leap years (and exact number of days in a month itself).

Comment: Excellent :) it worked. Sorry but I don't have reputation to flag it as Correct. Thanks for the help

Comment: Click the checkmark to mark it as correct, you have enough reputation for that. You just don't have enough for an upvote, thanks though!